# How to bulk delete 500 AWS EBS volumes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, bash, amazon-ec2

I have about 500+ AWS EBS volumes. I can filter them out with Volume State = available and the tag: year=2022.

How should I delete them in a bulk using Python or a bash script, since I can only delete 50 at a time using the console?

The AWS [delete-volume](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/delete-volume.html) does not have a "state" filter or a "tag" filter.

Answer (score 2):

The [gist script](https://gist.github.com/kenazk/bfdb23ef92bfe0db75099912c5c4547a) by Kenaz Kwa seems to be what you are looking for.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import boto3

sess = boto3.Session(
  aws_access_key_id="MYAWSACCESSKEYID",
  aws_secret_access_key="MYSECRETACCESSKEY",
  region_name="us-east-1",
)

ec2 = sess.resource('ec2')
volumes = ec2.volumes.all()

to_terminate=[]
for volume in volumes:
    print('Evaluating volume {0}'.format(volume.id))
    print('The number of attachments for this volume is {0}'.format(len(volume.attachments)))

    # Here's where you might add other business logic for deletion criteria
    if len(volume.attachments) == 0:
        for tag in volume.tags:
            if tag['year'] == '2022':
                to_terminate.append(volume)

if len(to_terminate) == 0:
    print ("No volumes to terminate! Exiting.")
    exit()

for volume in to_terminate:
    print('Deleting volume {0}'.format(volume.id))
    volume.delete()
```

The line with the code `if len(volume.attachments) == 0:` checks to see if the volume is attached to an EC2 instance.  You can modify this for whatever criteria you have.  For instance, does the name begin with 'x' or if the size is over x Gb.

Comment: what about the tag?